# How to calculate a line from a text file?

Tags: python

Just asking if there is a possible code or way to calculate an entire line from a text file.
For example, I have the following textfile;

```
Force    Displacement    Theta
0        0               0
15       0               0
3        0.15            0
1        1               90
-3       0.15            0
```

I want to calculate the WorkDone for these numbers line by line by using the equation

> W = Force * Displacement * cos(Theta)

I have tried;

```
fname = input("Please enter the filename: ")
infile = open(fname, "r")

with open(fname, 'r'):
     data = infile.readline()
     f,D,Theta = eval(data)
     display = f * D * cos(radians(Theta))
     output.setText(("%,2f") % display)
```

I have no idea what I did so please help

Comment: Where is the loop?  You are only getting the first line of the file.

Comment: Dont worry about that. I just want to know if there is a possible code to do this.

Comment: You mean: calculate an outcome for each line of an input text file?

Comment: Yes, That is all I want

Comment: From your question text and the context, that was clear to me.  The question itself could have been formulated better...

Comment: Io. Sai ke tau ilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would create a function for the parsing (`parse`), a function for the calculation (`work`).

```
def parse(line):
   return (float(token) for token in line.split())

def work(f, d, theta):
   return f * d * cos(theta)
```

And some problems: the opened file should have a name: `with open(...) _as infile_:`...  You don't have to open it before the `with...` block:

```
fname = input("...")
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.readline() # drop the first line
    for line in infile:
        f, d, t = parse(line)
        print(work(f, d, t))
```

This should more or less do the trick.